# Residue calculus: Integrals vanish

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, residue-calculus

> Let $a>0, \omega > 0$. We want to prove that $$\frac 1 {2 \pi i} \int_{\omega - i \infty}^{\omega + i \infty} \frac{a^z}{z(z+1)} dz = (0 \text{ if } a \in [0,1) \text{ and } 1-\frac 1 a \text{ if } a>1) $$ For that, we use the residue theorem with the following paths: [image]
>
> For $a \leq 1$, we get $0$ and for $a>1$ we get $1-\frac 1 a$ since the residues are $1$ and $-\frac 1 a$. **The integrals over the half circles vanish because for $R\rightarrow \infty$ the function value goes to zero with $O(R^{-2})$.**

Our convention here is: $$\frac 1 {2 \pi i} \int_{\omega - i \infty}^{\omega + i \infty} = \lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\gamma_M}$$ where $\gamma_M = \omega + i M t$ for $t\in [-1,1]$.

I understand everything but the bold part. Why do the integrals over the half circles vanish?

Comment: The observation that $$\left\lvert\frac{1}{(\omega+e^{i\theta}R)(1+\omega+e^{i\theta}R)}\right\rvert\leq\frac{1}{(R-\omega)(R-(1+\omega))}=\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{R^2}\right)$$ as $R\to\infty$ is probably useful